# rebase my branch on top of tree without caring of merge conflict

Tags: git, merge, clone, rebase

I have a script that has been stable and has not been changed for a while, so at the moment anyone that clones it to his machine, they need to tailor some configurations on it, some people including me, have branched out of Top of tree and then commit to his branch their custom settings/info, basically it is like this:

```
A - B - C         (main)
         \ - D1   (my_branch)
```

Now D1 is a commit that has changes that are configuration of my machine and its not usable by anyone
This has been working good enough, until now that we are adding some features, now the tree looks like this:

```
A - B - C  - E - F - G  (main)
         \ - D1         (my_branch)
```

I want to rebase my branch to be like this:

```
A - B - C - E - F - G       (main)
                     \ - D1 (my_branch)
```

how can I do so?

Comment: I feel like your title question implies something (about merge conflicts) that your question doesn't mention at all. Are you really looking for `git rebase main my_branch` or did you intend to ask about conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

From main branch just cherry-pick D1

```
git cherry-pick my_branch
```

From my_branch

```
git rebase main
```